# Array of objects, get the first object in the array

Tags: jquery

I have this:

```js
var dinosaursObjectArray = [
  { name: "Tyrannosaurus Rex", period: "Late Cretaceous" },
  { name: "Stegosaurus", period: "Late Jurassic" },
  { name: "Plateosaurus", period: "Triassic" }
];

var dinoArray = dinosaursObjectArray[0];
alert(dinoArray);
```

but the outcome is this [object object]

How to get the properties of the object?

Thank you

Comment: replace `alert(dinoArray);` with `console.log(dinoArray);`, press F12 to open the console and you'll see it. Don't use alert for debugging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `alert` function gets a string, so when you passed the `object` to that function you got the string-representation of that object.

You actually did get the object you were looking for, but you just didn't know it because you used `alert` for debugging (which is not a good practice). You better use `console.log` for that (you can open the developer toolbar to see the results of `console.log` using F12).

If you want you can convert the object to json string (using `JSON.stringify`) and alert the result:

```js
var dinosaursObjectArray = [
    { name: "Tyrannosaurus Rex", period: "Late Cretaceous" },
    { name: "Stegosaurus", period: "Late Jurassic" },
    { name: "Plateosaurus", period: "Triassic" }
];

var dinoArray = dinosaursObjectArray[0];
console.log(dinoArray);
alert(JSON.stringify(dinoArray));
```

Comment: Ah, oke. Thank you. nice

Answer (score 0):

Here you with a solution

```js
var dinosaursObjectArray = [
  { name: "Tyrannosaurus Rex", period: "Late Cretaceous" },
  { name: "Stegosaurus", period: "Late Jurassic" },
  { name: "Plateosaurus", period: "Triassic" }
];

var dinoArray = dinosaursObjectArray[0];
console.log("Name: ", dinoArray.name, ", Period: ", dinoArray.period);
```

For accessing a value inside an `object` please use `key`.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.stringify()` method to converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string. Please follow this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

If you want to get properties of the object you can do browser level debugging using `console.log` instead of `alert`. That's the best way to get properties of the object.

```
var dinoArray = dinosaursObjectArray[0];
console.log(dinoArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is general solution how to access properties of an object. Note that in OP `dinoArray.name` and `dinoArray['name']` are equivalent.

```js
var dinosaursObjectArray = [
                            { name: "Tyrannosaurus Rex", period: "Late Cretaceous" },
                            { name: "Stegosaurus", period: "Late Jurassic" },
                            { name: "Plateosaurus", period: "Triassic" }
          ];
var obj = dinosaursObjectArray[0];

for(var key in obj){
console.log(key + ': ' + obj[key]);
}
```